# Is this a usual approach to uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Consider $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $f_n : E\to \mathbb{R}$. The easiest form of convergence we can define is the pointwise convergence - we say that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ in $S\subset E$ if for each $x\in S$ the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges to $f(x)$.

Apart from that we can define uniform convergence. This is defined in the following way - we say that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $S\subset E$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there's $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ and if $x\in S$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. This is the same as endowing the space of functions with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and define convergence on this norm.

Now, in any case when we are given a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ and we want to discuss both forms of convergence we usually need to talk about the limit function $f$ which appears in both definitions.

With pointwise convergence it is quite simpler. We write down $f_n(x)$ and we have a usual sequence of numbers depending on a "parameter" $x$. We then study the convergence of this sequence depending on the possible values of $x$ and thus we get $f(x)$ by the usual methods of numerical sequences. Doing so for each $x\in E$ gives the limit function $f$.

To get the limit function $f$ on the case of uniform convergence things seems harder. We can't just look point by point because we are not considering things pointwise, but everything "as a whole" as I see.

Because of this I've been approaching the problem of studying uniform convergence of a sequence of function as follows:

First of all we notice that if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ then $(f_n)$ also converges pointwise to $f$. Because of this observation we look first at pointwise convergence. In that case I'm following these steps in general:

1. I pick $(f_n)$ and verify the pointwise convergence. If $(f_n)$ does not converge pointwise on $S$, then it cannot convergen uniformly also, since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.
2. If $(f_n)$ does converge pointwise on $S$ we look at the limit function we got, say $f$. If $(f_n)$ were to converge uniformly, since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence **with the same limit**, $(f_n)$ should converge to $f$. In that case we have a limit function to use with the definition.
3. We then apply the definition of uniform convergence to $f$ as limit function.

So this has been my approach, I've been first looking at pointwise convergence which is easier to study because it reduces to numerical sequences. And based on the fact that "uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence with same limit" I then study uniform convergence.

Is this the usual approach to uniform convergence? Or is there a easier way to study the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions?

Comment: This is the most natural approach to verify uniform convergence.

Comment: Though I tend to agree with Crostul's comment, you can also speak of a sequence of functions being _uniformly Cauchy_ without having a limit function in mind. It's straightforward to check (by the same proof as for numerical sequences) that a uniformly Cauchy sequence $(f_{n})$ of real-valued function has a pointwise limit $f$, and that $(f_{n}) \to f$ uniformly. That's one way to establish the Weierstrass $M$-test, for example.